# Simulink: Introduce delay with UDP Send/Receive

Tags: matlab, sockets, udp, simulink

I'm building a client/server-type subsystem in a control system application using UDP Send/Receive blocks in Simulink. Data *x* is sent to the server via UDPSend block which is then processed at the server that returns output *y*.

Currently, I've both the client (a Simulink model) and the server (processing logic return in Java) resides in the localhost. Therefore, the packet exchanges essentially take near-zero time. I'd like to introduce network delay such that the packet exchanges take a varying amount of time (say due to changes in bandwidth availability), effectively simulating a scenario where the server node is located in a different geographical location.

Could someone guide me on how to achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As a general (Simulink-independent) solution in a Windows environment, you should have a look at following [tool](http://jagt.github.io/clumsy/), which "makes your network condition significantly worse, but in a managed and interactive manner."